# How to export content from dev environment for deployment to production environment?

Tags: 8, nodes, deployment

We have to deploy content of around 37 content types from development to production environment. Each content type is having around 10 to 12 nodes. 
So, we have around 360 nodes for migrating to production environment.

How can i proceed it with at drupal end ?

Comment: Go through this, https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/deploy/drupal-to-drupal-deployment-between-two-or-more-sites

Comment: This module creates two workspaces over the same dev environment. By using this module, we can do deployment of each node one by one instead of bulk export & import.

Comment: Why can't configuration Export/Import be used?

Comment: @Kstack here my query is about content deployment not configuration deployment.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't done it myself but a colleague of mine had to do this last week. It's just exporting and importing the database. He used HeidiSQL with this link: https://support.appliedi.net/kb/a1034/how-to-import-and-export-a-mysql-database-using-heidisql.aspx

Comment: We want to export only content of content types instead of export and import of whole database dump.

Comment: Then only export the 'node' table with a content-type of the required type. You will also need the node_field_data table i guess along with some other 'node' tables

Comment: We have several dependencies of like term reference, entity reference type fields.